# Remove Space between NON ALPHA characters

Tags: regex

How can we remove the space between non alpha characters?

For example:

- `something or something`  - don't remove the space in between.
- `funcName  (  "fsd   fas"  )- funcName("fsd   fas")` - remove the space between non alpha character.

more Info:
Sorry for incomplete info
Im Using VB.net with .Net framework 2.0, windows xp sp 2 :)

till now i tried few thing but only one thing which was working closely was 
\s+(?![a-zA-Z])

this would remove only those spaces which are not followed by the letters...

Comment: do you want to do a `trim`? Give more examples please

Comment: (1) What have you tried so far? (2) what's so special about _or_?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Does it support lookbehind?

Comment: 'between non-alpha characters' suggests that both characters need to be non-alpha and the wording also rules out trimming; however, in your example only one non-alpha char seems to be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$content = preg_replace("/\s*(\W+)\s*/",$1,$content);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'$1'` rather than `$1`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming lookbehind is available, you need to use following regex to search:

```
/(?<=[^a-z])\s|\s(?=[^a-z])/
```

Then replace it by empty string "".

#### Live Demo in PHP: http://ideone.com/4fOEo3

**If lookbehind isn't available:** Use this regex:

```
/([^a-z])\s|\s(?=[^a-z])/
```

Then replace it by capture group #1 i.e. `'$1'`.

Comment: Who said lookbehind is available?

Comment: @JanDvorak: And who said its not? :P Not against you but I have seen these type of comments many times. Rather than getting clarifications of a vague questions from OP directly we start questioning each other. Hope you take this in right spirit.

Comment: You could state the limitation in the answer. "Assuming lookbehind is available..."

Comment: @hi All im using VB.net Framework2.0, need to process lots of data, that needs to trim all the white spaces, but the trim function will remove only white space in the end of the line.

Comment: hi anubahav,

    \s*(\W)\s* replace with $1

This worked liek charm and i couldn't work with positive look behind, i had some problem...